# PHP Form with 'Quantity' dropdown to insert that many rows of the data entered into form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, forms

first time actually posting something here.

So problem is:

1. A HTML form with various variables
2. A dropdown for Quantity that inserts the above data into MySQL table
   that many times. (So if dropdown put on 5 then on-form-submit
   inserts 5 rows of this data into the database table.)

What I've got working thus far:
Form works for single row insert.

**PHP form function:**

```
if ( $_POST['addlcd'] ) { //if this form submitted
    $db->query("INSERT INTO
      LCD
      SET
      `dateadded` = '".addslashes($_POST['frm_dateadded'])."',
      `orderid` = '".addslashes($_POST['frm_orderid'])."',
      `ordertype` = '".addslashes($_POST['frm_ordertype'])."',
      `device` = '".addslashes($_POST['frm_device'])."',
      `colour` = '".addslashes($_POST['frm_colour'])."',
      `oldwork` = '".addslashes($_POST['frm_working'])."',
      `Notes` = '".addslashes($_POST['frm_notes'])."',
      `readyby` = '".addslashes($_POST['frm_readyby'])."',
      `status` = '".addslashes($_POST['frm_status'])."',
      `completed` = '".addslashes($_POST['frm_completed'])."'
      ");
}
```

Can I do what I want to do purely in PHP using the _POST['quantity'] ??

I do have jquery/javascript in page so if thats a feasible option but would prefer PHP func file suggestions using the basic of what I have above.

Thanks for your time reading, if you need further info let me know :)

Oh, its a project that uses SMARTY 2.* and PHP 5.6 if that's at all helpful.

Comment: If 5 selected from quantity drop-down than same row will be inserted 5 times in DB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my understanding same row will be inserted in DB as selected no. of quantity.

Please try.

```
if ( $_POST['addlcd'] ) { 
    //if this form submitted

    //Fetch quantity dd value
    $quantity = !empty($_POST['quantity'])?$_POST['quantity']:0; 

    //Loop will be iterate for selected quantity numbers...
    for($i=0;$i<$quantity;$i++){
        $db->query("INSERT INTO
          LCD
          SET
          `dateadded` = '".addslashes($_POST['frm_dateadded'])."',
          `orderid` = '".addslashes($_POST['frm_orderid'])."',
          `ordertype` = '".addslashes($_POST['frm_ordertype'])."',
          `device` = '".addslashes($_POST['frm_device'])."',
          `colour` = '".addslashes($_POST['frm_colour'])."',
          `oldwork` = '".addslashes($_POST['frm_working'])."',
          `Notes` = '".addslashes($_POST['frm_notes'])."',
          `readyby` = '".addslashes($_POST['frm_readyby'])."',
          `status` = '".addslashes($_POST['frm_status'])."',
          `completed` = '".addslashes($_POST['frm_completed'])."'
          ");
    }    
}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you very much. Have selected as Answer :)